# How does "ほじくり返す" work in this sentence?

Tags: translation

I was reading Nagatoro where this girl is teasing her senpai. But she says this line that confuses me.

> 我慢するなら初めからほじくり返すからね

From what I've learned, I understand this goes like "If you endure, I'll disclose (it) from the beginning." Though, that sentence doesn't really make sense to me. Which is why I"m here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ほじくり返す is "to bring up again" or "to rehash" rather than "to disclose". Without more context, this sentence sounds to me like the girl is going to talk about the senpai's embarrassing past until he/she gives up. If it still doesn't make sense, please share more context.